# How do I create a external table in Athena from CSV file with JSON column in it

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have a CSV file in S3 which looks like:

```
id,name,secondary_id,created_at,last_modified_at,tags,report
2a-4c-4d-b0,foo1,103776194,2021-10-23 13:28:02.837511,2021-10-23 13:34:55.781556,"{""reports"": {""risk"": {""status"": ""ACTIVE""}, ""analysis"": {""status"": ""ACTIVE""}}}",health
2a-4c-4d-b0,bar1,103776194,2021-10-23 13:28:02.837511,2021-10-23 13:34:55.781556,"{""reports"": {""risk"": {""status"": ""ACTIVE""}, ""analysis"": {""status"": ""ACTIVE""}}}",risk
fc-ab-4a-8b,foo2,103101839,2021-10-23 12:54:25.662775,2021-10-23 12:56:54.53149,"{""reports"": {""risk"": {""status"": ""ACTIVE""}, ""analysis"": {""status"": ""ACTIVE""}}}",health
a9-2e-4e-b3,bar2,103776194,2021-10-23 13:23:35.286249,2021-10-23 13:35:22.340411,"{""reports"": {""risk"": {""status"": ""ACTIVE""}, ""analysis"": {""status"": ""ACTIVE""}}}",risk
```

I tried to use the query:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test_table`
(
  id STRING,
  name STRING,
  secondary_id STRING,
  created_at TIMESTAMP,
  last_modified_at TIMESTAMP,
  tags STRING,
  report STRING
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
LOCATION 's3://location/'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'skip.header.line.count' = '1'
);
```

But as there is a comma (,) in the tags it is not able to populate the table correctly and considers it as a different column.

Does anyone know how do I fix it? Thank you.

Comment: Did you try to use Glue Crawler on that data? It will create the relevant Struct for you.

Comment: I ran with Crawler, even after specifying the Customer CSV as well. You need to fix your data properly. You can do something like `{""reports"": {""risk"": {""status"": ""ACTIVE""}, ""analysis"": {""status"": ""ACTIVE""}}}` and use '`' as quote char with openCSV serde.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure it out. So, I used the library `OpenCSVSerde` and used `WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('separatorChar' = ',', 'quoteChar' = '"')`. So the `separatorChar` separates the columns and `quoteChar` defines the beginning of the column and its end.

So, even though all my other columns do not start with `"` it still interprets it correctly. Hope this helps.